# Throttling of Long sms using camel-smpp

Tags: apache-camel

I want to know how to do throttling on outgoing SMS's on camel-smpp endpoint with long sms .Long SMS breaks down smaller with max size of 160 chars. if i use camel throttling , it is applied on incoming messages instead of outgoing sms. But the behavior i need is  throttling on outgoing sms.

for example of my route is like :

```
<route id="firstsmsc" >
<from uri="seda:firstsmsc"/>
<throttle timePeriodMillis="1000">
<constant>8</constant>
<to uri="    {{smsc1.protocol}}://{{smsc1.username.producer}}@{{smsc1.host.mt}}: {{smsc1.port}}?password={{smpp1.enc.producerpassword}}&amp;enquireLinkTimer=30000&amp;transactionTimer=5000&amp;systemType={{smsc1.systemType}}&amp;sourceAddrTon={{CamelSmppSourceAddrTon1}}&amp;destAddrTon={{CamelSmppDestAddrTon1}}&amp;sourceAddrNpi={{CamelSmppSourceAddrNpi1}}&amp;destAddrNpi={{CamelSmppDestAddrNpi1}}&amp;typeOfNumber={{CamelSmppSourceAddrTon1}}&amp;numberingPlanIndicator={{CamelSmppSourceAddrNpi1}}&amp;lazySessionCreation=true"/>
</throttle>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

If either the smpp component or the SMSC breaks down your message payload into chunks of 160 characters, then throttling like you propose will not help you. From a Camel perspective there is just one exchange, not many. Maybe you can try and split your exchange payload by 160 characters and then throttle the resulting exchanges. Something along the lines of

```
<route id="firstsmsc" >
    <from uri="seda:firstsmsc"/>
    <split streaming=false, parallelProcessing="false" >
        <camel:bean ref="SMSSplitter" />
        <throttle timePeriodMillis="1000">
            <to uri="{{smsc1.protocol}}://{{smsc1.username.producer}}..."/>
        </throttle>
    </split>
</route>
```

Comment: if i use splitter  to split the long sms into short sms , it will be received as separate sms instead of one sms on the handset. handset combines the short sms into back to original long sms if it was splitted by smpp component. There is link for concatenating short sms into long sms:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS .

Comment: Sure. But if you do not split the message in Camel, I do not see how Camel could to the throttling of the resulting multiple messages for you. This seems like something your SMS gateway should do.

Comment: it seems splitting of long sms is done by camel-smpp or jsmpp. I think this functionality should be implemented either one of the two components to achieve output throttling.